# Custom URL query arguments or not?

Tags: php, get, url-routing

I'm redirecting all requests to index.php, which parses the URL and fires the appropriate controller based on it.

Is it a good idea to change the way query arguments appear in the URL?

like `http://site.com/somepage/sub-subpage/page=20,offset=100`. then parse those arguments and pass them to the controller, because it looks more readable.

Or should I stick with the $_GET thing? like `...http://site.com/somepage/sub-subpage/?page=20&offset=100`

Comment: Your ?page=20&offset=100 example most used everywhere and it's like "standart". In my opinion it's depend on user which method to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too good idea because you'll have to implement query parsing yourself. I see no advantages in this way. And if you use standard `?name=val&name=val` notation you have:

- Automatic parsing and storage to `$_GET[]`
- Possibility to start using POST in no time.
- Less possible vulnerabilites in parsing. At least they are known.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with standards and therefore its better you stick with `$_GET` thing.

Answer (score 1):

YAGNI - You ain't gonna need it. Don't think too much, just do it. Apart from a matter of taste (someone might say *"I dislike questions marks in my URLs"*), there is a lot of benefit to just use the common format that is just working and for which many parsers/function do exist. Additionally you find documents you can refer to if you're unclear about the format.

Comment: I've seen sites doing it. I think dell does it too.

Comment: If you log into the administration area of the Dell website you might see some other pattern there. For your case I don't see any reason why to introduce the overhead for no added functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you got nice urls (so called SEO friend URLs) even if you dont care google or its an admin area.

The reason for using nice url is

- Its more readable.
- You can change the parameter by hand.
- When you paste it to email, IM or other media the url makes sense.
- Ugly urls makes it difficult to read the actual values. Some times you need it.
- When you see the address bar it looks nice and clean and you know where you are.
- In ugly urls you dont know where you are. Each url seems a middle of no-where.

Creating clean url with a little help of mod_rewrite is not tough.

1. Rewrite all URI to your index.php as `/index.php/REQUESTED_URL`
2. In the `index.php` just parse the url and invoke controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is only interesting for SEO. Have a look at Googles opinion to this question: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html

So it makes sense when this "pseudo" URL defines a page with really different content (i.e. /user/clara, /user/tom ...) but avoid to put a dynamic variable like session IDs into this static form.

Comment: don't care about google, because this is for a restricted area (administration). already using "pseudo" urls, but I need to use query arguments as well because some pages take like 10 of them

Comment: You should also link the more appropriate, newer blog post about the query parameters as they give your URLs more semantics and google is looking for that.

Comment: @thelolcat then it makes no sense to me, because with query parameter you can access all variables simply by `$_GET` and don't have to parse your URL